# Create an array of a range of letters starting after A and finishing after Z ie (B to AC)

Tags: ruby, string, range

I am working with the Roo Gem and wanted to pull data from a spreadsheet based on standard A1 syntax.

I have columns in the spreadsheet beyond Z so Excel does the whole AA, AB, AC column positions.

I want to create an array for columns W to AH.

Ruby doesn't seem to like when the upper range extends past Z but hasn't started from A??

Any ideas how to `("B".."AC").to_a` and not get `[]`

Here is the basic problem in irb.

```
("A".."Z").to_a
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
("B".."Z").to_a
#=> ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
("A".."AC").to_a
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC"]
("B".."AC").to_a
#=> []
```

Comment: Sorry, i'd like to keep it short so using array ranges syntax. I can accept an alternative as long as it is short and easy to maintain.

Comment: `('B'..'Z').to_a + ('A'..'AC').to_a` too ugly?

Comment: Yeah I just did that one. I'll use it for now but thought I might be missing something obvious

Comment: Interesting. I expected [`String#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-upto) to handle this properly, but it fails as well. I've filed a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13663).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this?

```
("A".."AC").to_a.drop(1)
```

you can drop whatever number of `elements` you like and it just involves 1 range and 1 array creation..

> The integer could potentially be substituted for someting that returns the position of the letter in the alphabet.

```
class Array
  def from(column)
    drop(find_index(column).to_i)
  end
end

("A".."AC").to_a.from('F')
#=> ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC"]
```

Using `Range` class directly, thanks to @sagarpandya82

```
class Range
  def from(column)
    to_a.drop(find_index(column).to_i)
  end
end

("A".."AC").from('F')
#=> ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC"]
```

Comment: Hmm that's nice it you do start at B and it is easy to figure out how many letters to drop. But if it is somewhere in the middle might make for too much thinking. But it is short I'll give you that :)

Comment: Yeh it is. The integer could potentially be substituted for someting that returns the position of the letter in the alphabet. Either way, I'll give it a bit more time to see what others come up with. I am using this for now though so will accept as answer unless something leaner comes along. Cheers

Comment: sure, I am also thinking for better solution till then.. :)

Comment: We can also splat the array if assigning to a variable (which I am) `a=*("A".."AH").drop(22)`

Comment: This answer is what I was about to suggest. :)

Comment: @JayKilleen splat calls `to_a` anyway, and variable can be assigned with `to_a` too..

Comment: @SergioTulentsev gotcha this time :)

Comment: You can remove all references to `self` in your Array patch.

Comment: Suggestion: patch the `Range` class with `to_a.drop(find_index(column).to_i)`. Then you can write `("A".."AC").from('F')` etc.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 although it is working, why is it working? I couldn't find `find_index` method documented for `Range` class...

Comment: `find_index` is a method within the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) module and the [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html) class includes Enumerable:)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) to build-up an empty array. The loop breaks once the current value equals the second parameter. To return the newly-built array `o`, we pass `o` as an argument to `break`, which by default returns `nil`.

```
def cols a, b
  loop.with_object([]) do |_, o|
    o << a
    break(o) if a == b
    a = a.next
  end
end  

cols('W','AH')
 #=> ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH"]

cols("A","Z")
 #=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
 #    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

cols("B","Z")
 #=>  ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
 #     "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

cols("A","AC")
 #=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
 #    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
 #    "AA", "AB", "AC"]

cols("B","AC")
 #=> ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
 #    "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA",
 #    "AB", "AC"]
```

Answer (score 2):

A mathematical answer of this would be :

**A => AH = (A => W) + (W=> AH)**

so **W => AH = (A => AH) - (A => W)**

The programmatical answer of this :

```
("A".."AH").to_a - ("A"..."W").to_a
#=> ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH"]
```

The `...` in the second range makes it exclusive, i.e. without "W".

A more general answer would be

```
r = "W".."AH"

("A"..r.end).to_a - ("A"...r.begin).to_a
#=> ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH"]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I've replaced your `(string.ord-1).chr` with an exclusive range.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [`String#succ`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-succ) increments letters the way Excel increments column names:

```
'Z'.succ #=> "AA"
```

So if you *know* that the destination value is reachable via `succ`, a simple loop works:

```
ary = ['W']
ary << ary.last.succ until ary.last == 'AH'

ary #=> ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH"]
```

But with the wrong values, it can easily become an infinite loop.

---

For a more robust solution, you could write a custom class:

```
class Column
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    raise ArgumentError if name =~ /[^A-Z]/
    @name = name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    [name.length, name] <=> [other.name.length, other.name]
  end

  def succ
    Column.new(name.succ)
  end
end
```

It basically just wraps the column name, but it also takes the name's [`length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-length) into account:

```
[name.length, name] <=> [other.name.length, other.name]
```

This means that longer names come after shorter ones. Names with the same length are compared lexicographically.

This allows you to generate the wanted sequences:

```
r = Column.new('W')..Column.new('AH')
r.map(&:name)
#=> ["W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH"]
```