# Why is the difference between the Range objects 'A'..'AB' and 'B'..'AB' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, range

Can someone please explain me why

```
('A'..'AB').to_a
#=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB"]
```

but

```
('B'..'AB').to_a
#=> []
```

?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44558865/5101493) may interest you.

Comment: To see the same phenomenon in an even weirder situation, try
`('@'..'a').to_a` and `('@'..'aa').to_a` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of a discrepancy between [`String#succ`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-succ) and [`String#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E):

```
'a'.succ       #=> 'b'
'a' < 'a'.succ #=> true
```

but:

```
'z'.succ       #=> 'aa'
'z' < 'z'.succ #=> false
```

Range utilizes both, `succ` and `<=>` when generating a sequence. It uses `succ` to generate each successive value and checks via `<=>` that the values are indeed successive (ending the sequence if not).<sup>1</sup>

Even `String#upto` behaves this way. I've recently filed a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13663), because I'm under the impression that it should handle this properly.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the behavior for iterating *custom objects*. Range behaves more oddly for the built-in `String` class, maybe because of optimizations.

Comment: Also note that `('A'..'cc')!=('A'..'dd')`, but `('A'..'cc').to_a==('A'..'dd').to_a` Pretty cool, isn`t it? :-)

Comment: @GergelyMáté you are comparing apple and oranges: `1.0 == 1 #=> true` but `1.0.to_s == 1.to_s #=> false`

Answer (score 3):

`string1..string2` will list "all" strings between the two values **in "dictionary order"**.

More precisely, it will repeatedly call [`String#succ`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-succ) on `string1`, until it reaches `string2`.

```
"A".succ == "B"
"B".succ == "C"
# ...
"Z".succ == "AA"
"AA".succ == "AB"
```

On the other hand, if `string2 < string1` (i.e. "`string2` comes before `string1` in a dictionary"), then you get an empty range. There is a slight discrepancy here between the **initial use of `String#<=>` to check whether the range is "valid"**, and then reaching `string2` by calling `String#succ` on `string1`.

---

If you want to generate that list: `["B", "C", ... , "Z", "AA", "AB"]`, then you could specify a "valid" range and then remove the first element(s):

```
('A'..'AB').drop(1)
```

---

Suppose instead that you want to use two strings that are in the "wrong order" - e.g. `"BA"` and `"B"`. Note that this list will be counting "backwards":

```
["BA", "AZ", "AY", ... "AA", "Z", "Y", "X", ..., "C", "B"]
```

First note that this *will **not** work*, because `"BA" > "B"`:

```
("BA".."B").to_a
  # => []
```

Instead, you could convert the reversed range to an array and reverse it again:

```
("B".."BA").to_a.reverse
```

Or if you plan to loop through this list, it's more performant to use `reverse_each`:

```
("B".."BA").reverse_each { |x| ... }
```

Comment: _"because you will never be able to reach string2 by calling String#succ on string1"_ – you can reach `"AB"` from `"B"` by calling `succ`. The sequence is _B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB_

Comment: Yeah, you're right that there's a slight discrepancy between the use of `String#<=>` and `String#succ` - as per your bug report. However, I'm not sure what the correct "fix" is -- are you proposing implementing a second `<=>`-like operator?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your conclusion is wrong: you _can_ reach `string2` by calling `succ` on `string1`.

Comment: Regarding my bug report: you can't fix it for `Range` without breaking backwards compatibility for `String<=>` or `String#succ`. But you can fix it for `String#upto` by applying a more specialized logic. After all, it's a `String` method.

Comment: @Stefan But then, such a "fix" would mean that this statement is no longer true for any two strings: `s1.upto(s2).to_a == (s1..s2).to_a`. Anyway, we should probably discuss this in the bug report and not here :)

Comment: Even though `"Z".succ == "AA"`, `('Z'..'c').to_a` shows that it is not always going in 'dictionary order'...

Comment: @GergelyMáté My answer technically only applies to "normal" ranges. It is possible to construct some funny examples whereby it uses the [ascii table order](http://ascii.cl/) - so in this case, `["Z", "[", "\\", "]", "^", "_", "\`", "a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: Sometimes the values don't even appear in the array: `('0'..'999').to_a` and `('0'..'abc').to_a` both return the same array. `'abc'` is merely used as a width indicator (3 chars = 3 digits)

Answer (score 2):

`Range#to_a` internally calls the method `succ` of its "elements". Here is a non-official implementation of `Range#to_a`

```
class Range
  def to_a
    ary = []
    item = self.begin
    compare = self.exclude_end? ? :< : :<=
    while item.public_send(compare, self.end)
      ary << item
      item = item.succ
    end
    ary
  end
end
```

You can try `'A'.succ`, `'B'.succ`, ... to see the sequence it generates.

Because `'B'` is alphabetically greater than `'AB'`, the loop ends before the first iteration, thus you get `[]`.